# Next-absolute-url is not working in production in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, absolute-path

I used absoluteUrl in Nextjs for getting origin.
In localhost I'm getting the origin is **http://localhost:3000** this is fine.

But when I imported this origin to in socialshare buttons, I am getting the origin is **http://localhost:3000**  in production page

Can anyone tell me how to write code for production?

```
 const fetchRelative = (req: any) => {
     const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req);
     return origin;
 }
 const origin = await fetchRelative(reqObj);
```

I used this code in my page.

Comment: Where are you calling `fetchRelative` from? What's the value of `reqObj`?

Comment: I have the same problem with app deployed to Vercel.